# Run shell script at startup (Kali Linux)

Tags: shell, cron, startup, chmod

This seems like a very basic thing to do, and I have even followed a few tutorials to get a simple script to be run at startup, but to no avail.

Here is what my script, which is in the root directory, looks like:

```
#! /bin/bash
xmodmap ~/.xmodmaprc
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/iso_layout
```

The script basically changes my keymap, by switching control and command keys (as I'm on a macbook). It has been `chmod`'ed to be executable, so that it executes successfully  when I do `./keymap_fix.sh` or I do `/root/keymap_fix.sh`

I have followed these simple tutorials 
https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-run-a-command-when-boots-up.html and https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/

So, I have copied the shell script to `/etc/init.d` and did this also `update-rc.d keymap_fix.sh defaults 100`

I even tried setting up crontab in a similar way, by adding `@reboot /root/keymap_fix.sh` , but nothing works! Whenever I reboot, my keymap remains the same. :/

Would be grateful if someone could help me out here, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to run your script from .bashrc file?

Comment: I've answered the same question in here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560551/342948

Comment: @ram0nvaldez you should mark this question as a duplicate of that one

Comment: The `xmodmap` command needs to be run at *X11 session startup* instead, so that it will be able to communicate with the X server. Cron jobs, startup scripts and `systemd` system services all run in separate environments that have no connection with the X11 session, and some of them might even run too early, before the X11 server has even started.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [start script at boot for kali linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438851/start-script-at-boot-for-kali-linux)

Answer (score 1):

Commands like `xmodmap` can only run in X window,

You should create a `dot.desktop` file in the xdg autostart folder, e.g create a file `~/.config/autostart/startup.desktop` and put these lines in it:

```
Exec=~/bin/startup.sh
```

See [this link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries#Autostart) for details

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of [start script at boot for kali linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438851/start-script-at-boot-for-kali-linux)

I answered that one with these steps:

`sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service`

Then add the following content to it.

```
[Unit]
 Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
 ConditionPathExists=/etc/rc.local

[Service]
 Type=forking
 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start
 TimeoutSec=0
 StandardOutput=tty
 RemainAfterExit=yes
 SysVStartPriority=99

[Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note: Starting with 16.10, Ubuntu doesn’t ship with /etc/rc.local file anymore. Same thing for other distributions like Kali. You can create the file by executing this command.

```
printf '%s\n' '#!/bin/bash' 'exit 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/rc.local
```

Then add execute permission to /etc/rc.local file.

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

After that, enable the service on system boot:

```
sudo systemctl enable rc-local
```

Finally, start the service and check its status:

```
sudo systemctl start rc-local.service
sudo systemctl status rc-local.service
```

The complete post: [How to Enable /etc/rc.local with Systemd](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd).